# Getting just the Location from Header of cURL Request

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm trying to retrieve the location URL of an image after a redirect, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've never used cURL before, but from the research I've done it looks like I need it to get an image from Facebook. Here's my code so far:

```
function getImage($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
// Only calling the head
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // header will be at output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD'); // HTTP request is 'HEAD'

$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $content;
}

$image = explode("Location: ", getImage("http://graph.facebook.com/553451657/picture?type=large"));

print_r($image);
```

But my response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate Content-Type: image/jpeg Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT Location: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/161877_553451657_798840908_n.jpg Pragma: no-cache X-FB-Rev: 590433 X-FB-Debug: WH1uJvIjUqiLT8ezVPdude8VKYnXjAHRlFaP8gqF9fI= Date: Fri, 13 Jul 2012 17:56:09 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0 Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

How do I JUST get the Location part ("http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/161877_553451657_798840908_n.jpg")?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a function on the headers:

```
            $headers = [];

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $header) use (&$headers) {
                $matches = array();

                if ( preg_match('/^([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^\x0D\x0A]*)\x0D?\x0A?$/', $header, $matches) )
                {
                    $headers[$matches[1]][] = $matches[2];
                }

                return strlen($header);
            });
```

(seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37837808/php-curl-get-header-parameters))

Then you get it stored in `$headers["Location"][0]`.

I am also, like you, trying to get the fb page image this way, it seems no PHP SDK, App priviledges or access_token is needed for that, but there might be some limitations (anybody knows?)

Comment: wonder if you could just do ```$matches=explode(': ',$header,2); $headers[$matches[0]][] = $matches[1] ?? "";```

Answer (score -2):

> How do I JUST get the Location part

Getting that Location header is not you’re *primary* goal, right? You want to get the image from the address that’s being redirected to, correct?

So just set the option `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, and cURL will follow that redirect *automatically* and fetch the *real* image for you.