# PHP curl get header parameters

Tags: php, curl

I'm using curl with PHP for getting the header response of an API call.

This is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,            'http://localapi.com/v1/users');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array("authorization: Basic dmt5MVVTeXg3ZXpKYXVEZGtta2phZThfQ0tXa2tTQkY6"));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

The `$response` returna the header:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2016 13:48:43 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) PHP/5.5.31 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.31
>   X-Rate-Limit-Limit: 1 X-Rate-Limit-Remaining: 0 X-Rate-Limit-Reset: 0
>   X-Pagination-Total-Count: 1 X-Pagination-Page-Count: 1
>   X-Pagination-Current-Page: 1 X-Pagination-Per-Page: 20 Link: ;
>   rel=self Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 1

Is there a method for access to the single header variables like an array?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: split on line-breaks. every http header is a single line of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a callback for Curl to process the headers in the response using **[CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)**. By providing the `$headers` variable for the callback to assign the results, you can access them as an array after `curl_exec` has finished.

```
$headers = [];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function ($ch, $header) use (&$headers) {
    $matches = array();

    if ( preg_match('/^([^:]+)\s*:\s*([^\x0D\x0A]*)\x0D?\x0A?$/', $header, $matches) )
    {
        $headers[$matches[1]][] = $matches[2];
    }

    return strlen($header);
});

curl_exec($curl);
```

`$headers` will now contain an associative array of the response headers